# @predestroy of entity1 is being called on third redirect of any other entity in second tab

Tags: jsf, cdi, view-scope, predestroy

@predestroy of a page is being called whenever I redirect to another page in a new tab (for the third direction)

My controller is @ViewScopped from java.faces.view cdi and @named

the navigation to another page then to another page in a new tab
make the predestroy of the first card being called where if I have a datatable in the first tab
when navigating the datatable data disappered